# Building a Comparison

Tags: sentence-construction, writing, parallelism

Today, while I was watching a video on YouTube, I came across the following sentence:

> Contrary to my personality, my sister is very outgoing and tends to make friends easily.

From a meticulous academic writing view, I feel there is something off about the comparison that is established in the sentence: the two elements that are being compared to each other are *my personality* and *my sister* which doesn't make any sense. Thus, if I were to write this sentence, I would reconstruct it by adjusting either of the two elements:

> - Contrary to my personality, **that of my sister** is very outgoing and she always tends to make friends easily. (I am not totally satisfied with this one. Just trying)
> - Contrary to myself, my sister is very outgoing and tends to make friends easily

Can anyone clarify it a little bit and distinguish right from wrong?

Comment: Your observation is correct. I would express this as *Unlike me, my sister is very outgoing and tends to make friends easily.*

Comment: "a meticulous academic writing view"? Surely, you mean: a meticulous academic writing point of view. Anyway, Youtube is spoken not written.

Answer (score 1):

Although the original sentence may make sense or be accepted in everyday conversation, you are right; it does not entirely make sense.

> *Contrary to my personality, that of my sister is very outgoing and she always tends to make friends easily.*

The above sentence is much better, except for the fact that it seems you have forgotten the comma after *outgoing* to separate the two complete sentences. Otherwise, the sentence appears correct.

> *Contrary to myself, my sister is very outgoing and tends to make friends easily.*

This sentence works, too, but, because it is acting neither as an intensive pronoun nor as a reflexive pronoun, *myself* is not necessary and would actually be considered grammatically incorrect to many linguists (but I can see why you put that since it does add emphasis); *Contrary to me* would be a better option.